# Display a list of items of a specific user (by id) in One to many relationship Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

in my example here i want to display a list of appointments of a specific patient in a one to many relationships .. the process is going well but the problem is how to display this list which is in patient as an attribute.

**Appointment Entity**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.entities;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
@Entity
@Table(name="APPOINTMENTS")
@Data  @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString


public class Appointment {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateAppointment;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="patient_id", nullable=false)
    private PatientEntity patient;
}
```

**Patient Entity**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
@Entity
@Table(name="PATIENTS") 
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class PatientEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="NOM",length =25)
    private String nom;
    @Column(name="PRENOM",length =25)
    private String prenom;
    @Column(name="CIN",length=25)
    private String cin;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateNaissance;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<Appointment> appointmentList = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
}
```

**Appointment Repository**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.repositories;



import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.entities.Appointment;

public interface AppointmentRep extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Integer>{

}
```

**Patient Repository**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.entities.PatientEntity;


public interface PatientRep extends JpaRepository<PatientEntity,Integer> {
    public List<PatientEntity> findByNomContains(String name);

}
```

**Appointment Service**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.services;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class AppointmentService {
    
}
```

**Patient Service**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.entities.Appointment;
import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.entities.PatientEntity;
import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.repositories.AppointmentRep;
import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.repositories.PatientRep;

@Service
public class PatientService {
@Autowired
PatientRep patientRepository;
@Autowired
AppointmentRep appointmentRep;
//return a list of patients
public List <PatientEntity> getAllPatientEntity()
{
    List<PatientEntity> patients = new ArrayList<PatientEntity>();
    patientRepository.findAll().forEach(p->patients.add(p));
    return patients;
}
//search a patient by id
public PatientEntity getPatientEntityById(int id)
{
    return patientRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

// save a new patient
public void saveOrUpdate(PatientEntity patient)
{
    patientRepository.save(patient);
}
//delete a specific record
public void delete(int id)
{
        patientRepository.deleteById(id);
}
//update a record
public void update(PatientEntity patient, int patienId)
{
    patientRepository.save(patient);
}


}
```

**Appointment Controller**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.web;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AppointmentController {
    
}
```

**Patient Controller**

```
package ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.web;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.entities.PatientEntity;
import ma.ac.ensaf.cabinetmedical.services.PatientService;


@RestController
public class PatientController {
    @Autowired
    PatientService patientService;
    @GetMapping("/patients")
    private List<PatientEntity> listPatients()
    {
        return patientService.getAllPatientEntity();
    }
    @GetMapping("/patients/{id}")
    private PatientEntity monPatient(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        return patientService.getPatientEntityById(id);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    private void deletePatient(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        patientService.delete(id);
    }
    @PostMapping("/addPatient")
    private int savePatient(@RequestBody PatientEntity patient)
    {
        patientService.saveOrUpdate(patient);
        return patient.getId();
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/update")
    private PatientEntity update(@RequestBody PatientEntity patient)
    {
        patientService.saveOrUpdate(patient);
            return patient;
    }
    
    
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have many to one mapping in Appointment entity. you could write the below query in AppointmentRep

`List<Appointment> findAllByPatientId(int id);`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: If it helps, you could upvote the solution.